# Conditional Rendering of Parallel Next.js Routes onClick in Layout.jsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, onclick, next.js13

I'm facing an issue with conditionally rendering parallel routes in a Next.js application. I have two parallel routes, @home and @signin, each associated with its respective content. I'm trying to achieve conditional rendering of these routes within the layout.jsx based on an onClick event in the @signin route.

Here's the structure of my code:

```
// app/layout.jsx
const RootLayout = ({ signin, home }) => {

  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <main>
          {/* Conditional rendering should happen here */} // {boolean ? home : signin}
        </main>
      </body>  
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout;

// SignIn.jsx inside @signin
const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <button onClick={/* What should I put here? */}>
      Sign In
    </button>
  )
}
```

**What I Tried**
I initially attempted to create a separate component called HandleSignIn, within which I used the useState hook to manage a boolean value. Upon the onClick event, I updated this state variable to true. The idea was to default render @signin until the SignIn button was clicked updating the boolean for @home to be rendered.

**What I Expected**
I expected that upon clicking the "Sign In" button, the value state would change from false to true, and this updated state would then be used to conditionally render the appropriate route(@home) within layout.jsx.

**What Happened**
Of course that didn't happen because the root layout.jsx is rendered on the server and can't use 'use client' to manage the state boolean value.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click on `SignIn` button?